# issue in Ionic Keyboard ion-input focus

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-keyboard

I am working on ionic 4, i have create simple sign-in and signup page, and top of these pages there is my app logo which is sticky. when i focus on any of input field than that portion goes up side and i can not able to see what i am typing. as you can see in below image the blue line is my username input field,

i face this issue in both platform android and ios

How can i solve this issue?
i am new to ionic.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why the sticky part is sticky? It's because you made it sticky. :)

It's not a good idea because as you have just found with this scenario, things can get lost behind it.

And not everyone has the lastest phones, some have small screens and could experience the same thing.

Your logo is taking up about 40% the height of the screen. It's not right. You have to work with the limitations of mobile devices which means not trying to reserve that much space on the screen for the logo.

Comment: no, my question is why that part is going that much up side, if the input field is below keyboard part than it is just go to above keyboard like the position of login button.